# can't get component to show up with react-images?

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting null return from this component. What am I Missing???

```
import React from 'react';
import Lightbox from 'react-images';


const IMAGES = [
    { src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_b.jpg" },
    { src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg" },
    { src: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_b.jpg" }
];


class ImagesRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);
        this.gotoNext = this.gotoNext.bind(this);
        this.gotoPrevious = this.gotoPrevious.bind(this);
    }
    onClose(){

    }
    gotoNext(){

    }
    gotoPrevious(){

    }
    render(){

        return (
            <Lightbox 
                images={IMAGES}
                onClose={this.onClose}
                    onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
                    onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
            />  
        );
    }
}
```

This results in an empty div. Is there a required prop I'm missing?

http://jossmac.github.io/react-images/#getting-started

Answer (score 3):

It is not obvious from the documentation, but react-images will not render a grid/or a gallery of your images. It will only render the Lightbox component once a image is clicked.

So, in order to get what you want (which is a gallery of some kind, AND the light box component applied to images of that gallery, then you need more than just 'react-images'. You can render the images on their own, or with another gallery/grid npm library.

For example you can render an array of images with just the normal `<img>` tag. BUT, be sure that each  image has the "onClick" set to be a function that opens the Lightbox. see below:

```js
...

 <Grid imagesArray={thumbs} onClick={this.openLightbox.bind(this)} columns={3} padding={3} />
<Lightbox
 images={images}
 isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
 onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
 onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
 onClose={this.closeLightbox}
 currentImage={this.state.currentImage}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need `isOpen`. Try

```
  return (
        <Lightbox 
            isOpen
            images={IMAGES}
            onClose={this.onClose}
                onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
                onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
        />  
    );
```